# Trimming off uninitialized list values in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, trim

I'm writing something in prolog and the way I used append, it ends up returning a list like [a,b,c|_]. Is there any standard predicate (or simple way) to cut off all the uninitialized/arbitrary values?

Edit to add: Length won't work because the list could be of an arbitrary length, I don't know what it's going to be ahead of time, otherwise I would have already used that to trim it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check into why append is giving you a list like that.  Because observe this behavior of append that fixes the problem you are seeing:

```
?- append([a,b,c|_], X, L).
L = [a,b,c|X]
?- append([a,b,c|_], X, L), X=[].
L = [a,b,c]
```

Comment: I checked, it looks like the base case of one of my predicates was off. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `length/2` to this end!

```
?- Xs = [1,2,3|_], length(Xs, N).
   Xs = [1,2,3], N = 3
;  Xs = [1,2,3,_A], N = 4
;  Xs = [1,2,3,_A,_B], N = 5
;  ... .
```

However, it is not clear to me what you want to describe here. If you want to stick with the smallest solution use `once(length(Xs, N))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you're list isn't terminated with `[]`, you're almost certainly building your list incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can close an open list like this:

```
close_list([]) :- !.

close_list([_ | T]) :-
    close_list(T).
```

i.e. you have to walk through all the elements to reach the variable tail, and then bind it to the empty list.

Usage:

```
?- List = [a, b, C, d, 2.2 | _], close_list(List).
List = [a, b, C, d, 2.2].
```

If you hold a variable that is bound to the tail then it becomes much simpler:

```
?- List = [a, b, C, d, 2.2 | Tail], Tail = [].
List = [a, b, C, d, 2.2],
Tail = [].
```